# How to make a new form appear after all picture boxes have disappeared in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am designing a space invaders game and have 12 aliens displayed on the screen. Once all the aliens have been shot on the screen i would like to close the current form and open another form in vb.

The aliens are stored in an array like this:

```
Private Sub createarray()
    aliens(0) = alien1
    aliens(1) = alien2
    aliens(2) = alien3
    aliens(3) = alien4
    aliens(4) = alien5
    aliens(5) = alien6
    aliens(6) = alien7
    aliens(7) = alien8
    aliens(8) = alien9
    aliens(9) = alien10
    aliens(10) = alien11
    aliens(11) = alien12
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us your current attempt at this and any errors or issues.

Comment: @Greg it tried this: If Alien1.enabled=false then form6.show()                                                                                                 me.hide()                                                                                                      End if

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this into your code at the point where you want to check if all the aliens are dead

```
   Dim alldead As Boolean = True
    For Each alien In aliens
        If alien.enabled = True Then
            alldead = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If alldead Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form6.show()
    End If
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: For each loops excite me, what can I say. Hahaha